# Is there a form Level Method or Event that fires after the keyDown event of focused control not before?

Tags: c#, .net, keydown, keystroke

The following method occurs before the event parsed to focused control.

```
  protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

I want the exact opposite of this method, I meant I want a method or an event which occurs just after the child control's `KeyDown` event.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason not to just store the response, do your work then allow the response to bubble?

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    var ret = base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    DoSomething();    
    return ret;
}
```

If needs be, your `DoSomething()` method can take `msg`, `keyData` and even the return value from `base.ProcessCmdKey`. Depends what you need to do with it.

If that's no quite what you want, you'll need to explain "just after" a little better. How long after?

Comment: I want just after the  focused control's key down event fired

Comment: It seems to be your Answer is correct , I will check and mark yours as answers if it works.